# Calling a constructor of a class, inherited by multiple classes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, parameter-passing

Straight to the point:
I've got 2 classes. One stores one set of information, another - different information.

.h file

```
class Direction
{
private:
    std::vector<float> dir;
public:
    Direction(std::vector<float> objDir); ......};
```

.cpp file

```
#ifndef frw_dir_ed
#define frw_dir_ed
#include "frw_direction.h"
#endif

FRW::Direction::Direction(std::vector<float> objDir = { .0f, .0f })
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        dir[i] = objDir[i];
}
    Direction(float x, float y);
```

Another .h file:

```
class Position
{
private:
    float posX;
    float posY;
public:
    Position(float x, float y);
```

Another .cpp file:

```
#ifndef frw_pos_ed
#define frw_pos_ed
#include "frw_position.h"
#endif // !frw_pos_ed


FRW::Position::Position(float x = 0, float y = 0)
{
    setPos(x, y);
}
```

I also have a third class. This one inherits 2 previous.

```
class gameObj : public Position, public Direction
{
public:
    gameObj(float x, float y, std::vector<float> direction, bool renderable);

    gameObj(float posX, float posY, float dirX, float dirY, bool renderable);

    //some funcs, destructor

private:
    FRW::Position objPos;
    FRW::Direction objDir;
    bool isRendered;
};
```

That was a header file, now .cpp:

```
FRW::gameObj::gameObj(float x = 0.5f, float y = 0.5f, std::vector<float> direction = { .0f, .0f }, bool renderable = true) 
                                        : FRW::Direction::Direction(direction), FRW::Position::Position(x,y)
{
isRendered = renderable;
}

FRW::gameObj::gameObj(float posX = 0.5f, float posY = 0.5f, float dirX = .0f, float dirY = 0.f, bool renderable = true)
                                        : FRW::Direction::Direction(dirX, dirY), FRW::Position::Position(posX, posY)
 {
isRendered = renderable;
 }
```

C2456 compiler error: member function or nested class in costructor initializer list
Error   3   error C2535: 'void FRW::gameObj::__dflt_ctor_closure(void)' : member function already defined or declared.

Please, can anyone tell me, which concept of OOP I missed?  Why I am getting this error?

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Not sure what that error is saying, but why do you have `gameObj` both inherit the other classes and also store the other classes as members?

Comment: Slightly off topic, but you should read up on when to use inheritance. Is a game object a position and a direction? If not then it shouldn't inherit from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to inherit from a class or have an element of that type as a member, not both! i.e. this:

```
class gameObj
{
public:
    // ...

private:
    FRW::Position objPos;
    FRW::Direction objDir;
    bool isRendered;
};
```

or this:

```
class gameObj : public Position, public Direction
{
public:
    // ...

private:
    bool isRendered;
};
```

but not this:

```
class gameObj : public Position, public Direction
{
public:
    // ...

private:
    FRW::Position objPos;
    FRW::Direction objDir;
    bool isRendered;
};
```

(Actually it's possible you'd want the last one, but very rare in practice.) With the last one, you end up with **two** directions in `gameObj`: the `gameObj::objDir` member, and the direction that the gameObj inherits from. In this case you probably want the member variable (a person *has* a direction, but it's not true that a person *is* a direction).This is called using composition rather than inheritance, and it's usually best if you can get away with it. As guide, you normally shouldn't use inheritance unless you need virtual functions. The reason for the compilation error is that you're only initialising one of those two directions (and one of the two positions).

By the way, the error would have been hidden by the fact that you have default values for the constructors. But they need to be in the header than the .cpp (otherwise only code in the .cpp after the definitions will "know" about the defaults).

Edit: Additionally, the code `FRW::Direction::Direction(dirX, dirY)` should be `FRW::Direction(dirX, dirY)`. This is the real cause of the compilation error (but once you fix it I think you'll get the error I mention above).

Comment: daym. Thank you very much.